# Highlight characters in word, keep capital

Tags: php

I'm trying to highlight (Bold) certain characters in a word. I replace the character with the same character plus the bold tags `<b></b>`. When I change the first character, it's lowercase. I want this to be capital. But because of the bold tags around it I can't use ucfirst(). I got it to work but I'm wondering if this can be done easier?

From: Testing
To:   **T**es**t**ing

```
<?php

$str = 'Testing';
$key = 'T';

$bold = str_ireplace($key , "<b>". $key ."</b>", $str);
    $allLower = strtolower($bold);

$arr = str_split($allLower);

if($arr[0] == '<'){
    $arr[3]= ucfirst($arr[3]);
}else{
    $arr[0]= ucfirst($arr[0]);
}

$string = null;

foreach($arr as $value){
    $string .= $value;
}

echo $string;

?>
```

Comment: I don't know if the first character is always uppercase in your use-case, but if it is you could use css `<span style="text-transform:capitalize;"><b>t</b>es<b>t</b>ing</span>`

Comment: What is the reason of `$allLower = strtolower($bold);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace('/t/i', '<b>$0</b>', 'Testing');
```

`i` at the end of `/t/i` stands for case insensitive matching, and `$0` represents the matched pattern in the replacement.

Hope this helps.